# Time Machine - cannot access all TM backups

Tags: macos, time-machine

I have a senior pal who came to me for help and I am stumped.

He just ran the latest incremental update to Ventura on a fairly new iMac (not Silicon) and he lost all the many mailboxes he had set up in the Mail.app because he choose to set up those mailboxes On My Mac and not in iCloud.

When he went to [Browse Time Machine Backups] he cannot go back any farther than one day, 24 Feb, even though he had backups over a year old. Looking at those little tick marks on the right side of his screen when browsing time machine, all are the same color save the one for 24 Feb, which bears a red tick mark.

Is there any app/terminal command/whatever one could use to repair his Time Machine so that he can access the backups made before this latest incremental update within Ventura?

Is there any other way to get at the contents of a TM Backup prior to 24 Feb?

Greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: TM can only keep what it can based on the space available  on the target.  How much of your IMac’s drive is consumed and how big is your TM drive?

Comment: What is visible on the backup disk via Finder at eg.. `/Volumes/Time Machine Disk`? Backups can be drilled into that way also, if you are sure of the date & time to recover from.  Another possibility is that the backup disk has not been connected properly. TM will keep also scheduled local snapshots for 24 hours (which would seem to match your time period) on the local disk so that some backup can be maintained even if the external disk is unavailable. If the external disk is not connected, the TM UI will present those as a minimum.

Comment: @Allan - His TM is a 1TB Glyph HDD of with about 1/3 or so of free space left.  The drive itself is about 3 years old.

Comment: How much space left on the iMac?

Comment: @ Andy.  As to the connection, I failed to ask him and just texted him asking for an answer.  He was using an old Time Capsule last time I connected with him.  I will post here as soon as he replies to my query.  (OK, another friend who tries to help him says his Glyph HD is connected directly to his Mac. He want to recover from a 2023-02-15 TM backup.  Question please:   Does /Volumes/Time Machine Disk mean going into the TM icon on the desktop, finding the correct date and file and dragging it to the desktop???

Comment: Going via the TM icon on the Desktop is one way of accessing it, yes (there are others). Once in there you should see a number of other icons, each representing a backup. In each of those you will find an icon representing the Data volume as it was when the backup was taken. And so deeper... till you get to the data to restore. It can be copied from there, but letting the TM UI do it properly is more safer. The question was posed to see whether the backups are visible in that form, not necessarily to suggest that's the best way of restoring from them, but if that works then go ahead.

Comment: @Allan - tons of space on his MacintoshHD1 TB SSD.

Comment: @Andy. Thanks. My TM is working so I did what you suggested, navigated to my ~/Library/Mail/V10 folder and dragged and dropped that folder onto my desktop...and  your suggestion did indeed work.
I followed this up with a screen sharing session with my buddy and to my disappointment, his TM machine path was not the same as mine.

In Colunn View, we were able to navigate to his home folder, but in the next column over not only was there no Library folder but also about 1/3 of the folders appearing in the Home folder bore that "no-entry" logo, like a no-enty sign on the street

Comment: I can only guess it hasn't inherited the old backup, so thinks it belongs to someone else. I've never done this, but see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh35732/mac

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop on this problem:
What he finally did was to purchase BackupLoupe, got into his 15 Feb TM backup, found the V10 folder, replaced his current "corrupted" V10 folder with it, got back the many mailboxes he had created On My Mac, but all of them were empty.  The hundreds of emails that once populated those mailboxes were gone.